# Checking if entity exist in Google App Engine Datastore using JPA 1

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

Below is my method in checking if entity already exist.

```
public boolean isExist(String genreName) throws PersistenceException{
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    boolean flag = false;

    try{
        Genre genre = em.find(Genre.class, genreName);
        if (genre != null)
            flag = true;

    }finally{
        em.close();
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Is the code above ok? Please suggest.

Comment: see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/598/google-application-engine-tag-synonym-request for tag synonym request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `isExist` is not English. Call it something like `genreExists`.
- In addition to omitting the flag, as palacsint suggested, you can get rid of the if branch:

---

```
public boolean genreExists(String genreName) throws PersistenceException {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        return em.find(Genre.class, genreName) != null;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

---

*Probably irrelevant side note:*

If you were using Java 7, and EntityManager implemented `AutoCloseable` or one of its various subinterfaces (such as `Closeable`), your code could be even cleaner using the new [*try-with-resources statement:*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try (EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager()) {
    return em.find(Genre.class, genreName) != null;
}
```

But  it doesn't, so you can't.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GAE, don't know if `EMF.get().createEntityManager()` is mockable. If not there could be difficulties if we want to cover this function with unit tests.

Comment: But looks like it is :) so just ignore my comments :)

Answer (score 5):

It looks fine. You could omit the boolean flag if you return immediately when you know the answer:

```
public boolean isExist(final String genreName) throws PersistenceException {
    final EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    try {
        final Genre genre = em.find(Genre.class, genreName);
        if (genre != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: if return immediately, `em.close` will not be executed?

Comment: @JRGalia the *finally* block is *always* executed.